# How store windows auth information in database

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, wcf, authentication

I have an application in an intranet scenario: windows form, using wcf transport security and windows authentication ([using this pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949032.aspx)). And I need to store windows users information and connect the windows user in my table "Person" (using Sql Server). But I have no idea what the best way to do this. Anyone can help me in a way to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet is to store the user's SID, this will never change for a given user, whereas the login name can be changed.  If you can get to the WindowsIdentity for the user, the SID is in the [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a table that stores the windows user name and the associated Person entry.